# Compile importing file when file being imported changes?

Tags: compass-sass

So if I have an aggregate file with imports in it:

```
@import "global"
@import "menus"
@import "datepicker"
@import "index"
@import "drawers"
```

Is there a way to have that file compile when any of the things it is importing change?

Answer (score 0):

Yes can make it possible with grunt

http://gruntjs.com/

Here is complete workflow of grunt + compass

http://matthew-jackson.com/notes/development/grunt-workflow-for-sass-compass-and-js/